# Connect scala-hbase to dockered hbase

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, hbase

I am trying play-framework template "play-hbase".
It's a template so I expect it works in most cases.
But in my case hbase is running with boot2docker on Win 7 x64.
So I added some config details to template:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  val barsTableName = "bars"
  val family = Bytes.toBytes("all")
  val qualifier = Bytes.toBytes("json")

  lazy val hbaseConfig = {
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    // ADDED ADDED specify boot2docker vm
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.59.103")
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
    conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.59.103:60000");
    val hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)

    // create a table in HBase if it doesn't exist
    if (!hbaseAdmin.tableExists(barsTableName)) {
      val desc = new HTableDescriptor(barsTableName)
      desc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(family))
      hbaseAdmin.createTable(desc)
      Logger.info("bars table created")
    }

    // return the HBase config
    conf
  }
```

It is being compiled and runs, but shows "bad request error" during this code.

```
def addBar() = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    // create a new row in the table that contains the JSON sent from the client
    val table = new HTable(hbaseConfig, barsTableName)
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(UUID.randomUUID().toString))
    put.add(family, qualifier, Bytes.toBytes(request.body.toString()))
    table.put(put)
    table.close()
    Ok
  }
```

Comment: Hi @user3003873 , Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Moved to parquet files ;-)